# i am trying to write a code to cross correlate a transmitted signal with a received signal to determine the number of samples delay

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, cross-correlation

Cross correlation is to be used to measure distance to an aircraft by transmitting a
known wide-band signal and correlating the transmitted signal with incoming signals
received via the radar reception dish

The transmitted signal x(n) is of length N=512 while the received signal y(n) is of length N=2048.

y(n)=kx(n-d)+w(n); where 'kx(n-d)' is x(n) delayed by d samples and attenuated by a factor k, and w(n) is reception noise.

i am trying to write a MATLAB program to cross correlate x(n) with the y(n) to determine the value of d, the number of samples delay.
And also Determine a suitable sampling frequency if the distance to the aircraft is to be
determined within 50 km to an accuracy of 50 m, given that the transmitted
and received data is travelling at the speed of light.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is with the "xcorr" function. This is part of the Signal Processing toolbox for matlab, but should be available for GNU Octave [here](http://octave.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/octave/trunk/octave-forge/main/signal/inst/xcorr.m?revision=HEAD&content-type=text/plain). I have not checked if the octave script is completely MATLAB compatible.

You can use the xcorr function as:

```
[correlation,lags] = xcorr(x,y);
```

The lag value can be found using

```
delay = lags(find(correlation==max(correlation)))
```

At the speed of light, the signal will be travelling at 3 x 10^8 m/s, so to have a resolution of 50m, you should be sampling at at least (3e8/50m) = 6MHz. At this sampling rate, each lag will be 1/6000000 second. If you multiply your delay by this value, you get your total time intervel between transmission and reception of the signal. Multiply this time intervel by the speed of light to get your distance.

Comment: No problem. If an answer solves your question, you should click on the green checkmark next to the answer so that the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 3):

You can use generalized Cross correlation -Phase transform GCC PHAT
The following is the MATLAB code for it

```
function time=GCCPHAT_testmode(b1,b2)

b1f=fft(b1);

b2f=fft(b2);

b2fc=conj(b2f);

neuma=(b1f).*(b2fc);

deno=abs((b1f).*(b2fc));

GPHAT=neuma./deno;

GPHATi=ifft(GPHAT);

[maxval ind]= max(GPHATi);

samp=ind

end
```

Answer (score 3):

we can ignore the 'find' function in matlab, the command could be changed to

```
delay = lags(correlation==max(correlation))
```

'xcorr' suits for vectors with long length;
'gcc' prefer frame by frame.

Answer (score 2):

Aj463's comment above is good, indeed GCC-PHAT is better than unweighted correlation for  estimating  delay of wide-band signals.

I would suggest a small improvement to the code posted above: to add a small value epsilon to the denominator, epsilon -> 0, in order to avoid eventual division by zero.

Thus, I would change the line

```
deno=abs((b1f).*(b2fc));
```

to

```
deno=abs((b1f).*(b2fc)) + epsilon;
```

Comment: Hi I implemented GCC-PHAT as you and Aj463 suggested but found its performance to be worse than normal cross-correlation. Would you be willing to take a quick look and help out? Thanks ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631904/gcc-phat-cross-correlation-in-python