# GCC-PHAT cross correlation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, signal-processing, cross-correlation

I am trying to implement GCC-PHAT in python.

The approach is similar to the following two links:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788005/i-am-trying-to-write-a-code-to-cross-correlate-a-transmitted-signal-with-a-recei) and [link2](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/Speech/papers/multimic/phat_delaysum.m)

It seems the only difference between GCC-PHAT and normal cross-correlation using FFT is the division by the magnitude.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import rfft, irfft, fftfreq, fft, ifft

def xcorr_freq(s1,s2):
    pad1 = np.zeros(len(s1))
    pad2 = np.zeros(len(s2))
    s1 = np.hstack([s1,pad1])
    s2 = np.hstack([pad2,s2])
    f_s1 = fft(s1)
    f_s2 = fft(s2)
    f_s2c = np.conj(f_s2)
    f_s = f_s1 * f_s2c
    denom = abs(f_s)
    denom[denom < 1e-6] = 1e-6
    f_s = f_s / denom  # This line is the only difference between GCC-PHAT and normal cross correlation
    return np.abs(ifft(f_s))[1:]
```

I have checked by commenting out `fs = fs / denom` The function produces the same result as normal cross correlation for a wide band signal.

Here is a sample test code which shows the GCC-PHAT code above performs worse than normal cross-correlation:

```
LENG = 500
a = np.array(np.random.rand(LENG))
b = np.array(np.random.rand(LENG))
plt.plot(xcorr_freq(a,b))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.correlate(s1,s2,'full'))
```

Here is the result with GCC-PHAT:

[image]

Here is the result with normal cross-correlation:

[image]

Since GCC-PHAT should give better cross-correlation performance for wide band signal, I know there is something wrong with my code. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ might have more folks with the relevant expertise. Please delete this question if you repost it there.

Comment: Why is your test code using `a` and `b` (two completely random signals) as inputs to `xcorr_freq` and using `s1` and `s2` (presumably some other signal) as inputs to `np.correlate` instead of comparing apples with apples by using the same inputs for both implementations?

Answer (score 1):

do not feed the GCC-PHAT with only noise. Give it a signal + noise. Check how GCC-PHAT and unweighted correlation compare as signal-to-noise ratio varies.